# Level curves of function at z=0

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2ye^{x+3y}$. Setting it equal to zero, we get $x=1$ or $y=0$. According to my understanding, these two lines should be the level curves. However, if I plot the function using a 3D plotter (GeoGebra in my case), it only seems to show $y=0$ as the level curve (the black line in the figure). Am I missing something?

[image: The function f(x,y) and its level curve]

Comment: I mean, by looking at the sheet of the graph, you can also clearly see that $x=1$ is a level curve (can you see that the function is completely flat there?)

Comment: Yes, I can see that, and it is clear from the algebra as well. But the software doesn't seem to be showing it. I have tried it with another plotter as well so may be it isn't a bug?

Comment: As a follow up question, any observations regarding continuity/differentiability of the function at the stationary points?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You're missing that the set of points where $f(x, y) = 0$ is different from the set of floating-point-number-pairs where the numerical evaluation of $f(x, y)$ yields a value that is numerically equal to zero. To be honest, I'd have expected the zeroes along the $x = 1$ line to show up, but they are cursed by being double-zeroes, i.e., they have the property that an arbitrarily small perturbation of the graph can make them disappear, and such zeroes are notoriously hard to find when using numerical computations.

The key thing here is that you're using tools at the boundary of two related but distinct domains: mathematics and computer science. Places where things are a little sensitive (like even-order zeroes of a function) are likely to fall into the gaps between  the two domains, sadly. The secret to not being surprised is to understand both domains deeply. Alas, very few people find that to be worth their time.

Comment: Interesting how computer science based largely on mathematical logic can give different results!

Comment: You might find it worthwhile to read the IEEE floating-point specification, or (if you're less ambitious) https://floating-point-gui.de/ .